# Prevent form from submitting with vue.js and axios

Tags: php, vue.js, axios

My problem is that when i click one of the buttons, it redirects me to the action="/validarfavorite.php" and i just want to submit the form without refreshing the page. This is my code:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
            <?php
echo"
<form method=\"POST\" @submit.prevent=\"onSubmit\" action=\"/validarfavorite.php\" style=\"display:inline-block\">
<div id=\"app\">";
if($row_cnt == 0) {
  echo"
<button type=\"submit\" value=\"Add to favorites\" style=\"font-weight: 700;color:#428bca;margin-left:30px;height:30px;border-radius:4px\" name=\"favorites\" @click=\"show = !show\" v-if=\"show\">Add to favorites</button>
";}
if($row_cnt == 0) {
  echo"
<button type=\"submit\" value=\"Delete from favorites\" style=\"font-weight: 700;color:#428bca;margin-left:30px;height:30px;border-radius:4px\" name=\"delete\" @click=\"show = !show\" v-else>Delete from favorites</button>
</div>
";}
echo"</form>";
?>


    <script>
new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data:{
    show: true
  },
  methods: {
          onSubmit: function() {
            axios.post('/validarfavorite.php')
          }
        }
});
</script>
```

if for some reason you need validarfavorite.php. But this is working well.

```
<?php
// ini_set('display_errors', 1);
// ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
// error_reporting(E_ALL);
include('config.php');

$get_palette_id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$select_palette = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id FROM palettes WHERE id = '$get_palette_id'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_palette);
$palette_id = $row['id'];
$amount_of_favorites = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM favorites where paletteid = '$palette_id'");
$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($amount_of_favorites);

// if(isset($_COOKIE["type"])){

if (isset($_POST['favorites']) && ($_POST['favorites'] == 'Add to favorites')) {
//el select del id de la paleta esta lo mas arriba por el num rows

  $cookie_id = $_COOKIE["type"];
  $select_userid = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE cookie = '$cookie_id'");
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_userid);
  $user_id = $row['id'];

  $insert_palette_id = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO favorites ( paletteid, userid ) VALUES ('$palette_id','$user_id');");
}

if (isset($_POST['delete']) && ($_POST['delete'] == 'Delete from favorites')) {
  $cookie_id2 = $_COOKIE["type"];
  $select_userid2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE cookie = '$cookie_id2'");
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_userid2);
  $user_id2 = $row['id'];
  $delete_palette_id = mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM favorites WHERE paletteid = '$palette_id' AND userid = '$user_id2'");
}
?>
```

Please help, i only have this left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `@:submit.prevent="onSubmit"` correctly, just remove the form action and handle everything in your `onSubmit` function.

PD. you likely also need to send info to your axios.post (the form data) currently you are only making an empty POST

Comment: i think the problem is type="submit", i should be using type="button". but i dont know how to recognize if a type="button" was clicked with php.

Comment: considering your way, where do i put the queries?

Comment: using submit is the standard way, you could use botton and check if it was clicked with more js but no case in that.

Comment: for the other thing, check axios documentation on how to send data. Then change your php to handle that data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Vue or Axious, but in general...
Instead of using button with a type of "submit", set the type to "button", thus... `<button type=\"button\" ... />`  This will allow the button to be detached from form submission.

Answer (score 0):

To make things simpler, add an `id` to that form, say:

```
echo"
<form id="favoriteForm" method=\"POST\" @submit.prevent=\"onSubmit\" action=\"/validarfavorite.php\" style=\"display:inline-block\">
<div id=\"app\">";
```

And then you can [get the `FormData` from the `<form>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) and submit it using `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'`:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    show: true
  },
  methods: {
    onSubmit: function() {
      axios({
          method: 'post',
          url: '/validarfavorite.php',
          data: new FormData(document.getElementById("favoriteForm")),
          config: {
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
          }
      })
      .then(function(response) { console.log('success', response); })
      .catch(function(response) { console.log('error', response); });
    }
  }
});
```